# How can I convert a CQL bigint type to date?

Tags: datetime, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra and I have a column of data that represents epoch time milliseconds stored as a `bigint` type:

```
request_time bigint
```

I would like to convert this to a date time object in order to work with certain days. How can I achieve that conversion?

I have tried:

```
select todate(request_time)

# InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Input type Int64 is not supported in ToDate."
```

and also:

```
select dateof(mintimeuuid(request_time))

# InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce Int64 into type CassandraTimestamp"
```

My Cassandra version is:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function -

```
todate()
```

Example below -

```
select request_time from testkspc.test;

 request_time
---------------
 123344345
 123344687
 123456329
 223344687
 1613808000000
 323344687
 123456789
 123344329
 423344687
 523344687
```

```
select todate(request_time)  from testkspc.test ;

 system.todate(request_time)
-----------------------------
                  1970-01-02
                  1970-01-02
                  1970-01-02
                  1970-01-03
                  2021-02-20
                  1970-01-04
                  1970-01-02
                  1970-01-02
                  1970-01-05
                  1970-01-07
```

Further you can use `totimestamp` function.
Directly using this function on bigint type gives error -

```
select totimestamp(request_time)  from testkspc.test ;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid call to function totimestamp, none of its type signatures match (known type signatures: system.totimestamp : (date) -> timestamp, system.totimestamp : (timeuuid) -> timestamp)"
```

We can wrap `todate` inside `totimestamp`.

```
select totimestamp(todate(request_time))  from testkspc.test ;

 system.totimestamp(system.todate(request_time))
-------------------------------------------------
                 1970-01-02 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-02 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-02 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-03 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 2021-02-20 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-04 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-02 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-02 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-05 00:00:00.000000+0000
                 1970-01-07 00:00:00.000000+0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got this however:

`cqlsh> select todate(request_time) from my_table ;

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Input type Int64 is not supported in ToDate."`

Comment: The version I tried is a bit higher - "cqlsh 6.8.0 | Cassandra 4.0.0.6816 | CQL spec 3.4.5"

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea by using the built-in CQL function `toDate()`.

I've deployed a Cassandra 3.11.0 cluster (the same as the version you're running) and can confirm that it works. Here's an example output:

```
cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT request_time, todate(request_time) FROM testbigint ;

 request_time  | system.todate(request_time)
---------------+-----------------------------
 1654671885000 |                  2022-06-08
          1654 |                  1970-01-01
```

In your case, I believe the underlying issue is that your table contains invalid data in the `request_time` column. You need to check the data in your table and try again.

As a side note, Apache Cassandra 3.11.0 was released 5 years ago and you shouldn't even bother using it for testing. At the time of writing, the current supported version is C* 3.11.13. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick! I still got this: `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Input type Int64 is not supported in ToDate."`

Comment: Let me see about 3.11.13.

Comment: Well, unfortunately since this is coming from CosmosDB on Azure, Cassandra 3.11.0 is all I have at the moment.

Comment: @mobiusinversion what values do you have for `request_time` in your table?